# Running Multiple Functions parallelly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have created a GUI using powershell to retrieve information from a remote server. As part of that I have 3 text boxes which populate the data when clicked on the button.

When clicked on the button it executes a function lets call it Function 'X'. Function X calls 3 more functions (lets calls them A, B and C) which intern populate those 3 textboxes.

My question is that how do I run those 3 function simultaneously as currently they run one at a time.

```
Function X(
   Function A
   Function B
   Function C

)
```

Example

```
Function A{
    $txtResultSvc.ForeColor=[Drawing.Color]::Black
    $res=Check-Something
    if($res -eq 999){
        $txtResultSvc.ForeColor=[Drawing.Color]::Red
        $txtResultSvc.Text=$blank
    }
    Else{
        $server="Servername"
        Disable-AllButtons
        $txtResultSvc.Text="Connecting to $server"
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 2 -Quiet){
            $txtResultSvc.ForeColor=[Drawing.Color]::Green
            $txtResultSvc.Text="Connected. Getting System Info from $server"
            $resulttextsvc=Get-ABC -store $server
            if($txtResultSvc.Text -ne $null){
                $txtResultSvc.Text=""
                $txtResultSvc.ForeColor=[Drawing.Color]::Black
                $txtResultSvc.AppendText((($resulttextsvc| Out-String -Width 1100).Trim()))
                $txtResultSvc.SelectionStart=0
            }
        }
        Else{
            $txtResultSvc.ForeColor=[Drawing.Color]::Red
            $txtResultSvc.Text="Unable to connect to $server"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is, are these 3 functions updating the same objects by any means? You need to consider if there is thread safety on the actions performed by your functions

Comment: Wouldn't an adverb be 'parallelily'?  There's always foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7, but it would be easier if the functions were in scripts or a module.

Comment: I do not recommend building multi-threaded GUI apps using PowerShell, it is not made for it and the amount of messing around to achieve it is not worth the effort imo. If you really want to create a GUI for your scripts I recommend using https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-universal or another dashboard tool.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - The functions are not updating anything. Two of the functions are just getting info out from GET API's and one of the function is hitting the sql server to get info from couple of tables. They all should be able to run at the same time without impacting anything.

Comment: @ThomErnst - I understand what you are trying to say, but this is for a small project and PS-Universal has a price tag attached to it.

Comment: @js2010 - I can only use Powershell 5 as this is a Windows 2008 R2 Server (Dont judge, we are still outdated).

Comment: You can install the Threadjob module in ps 5.

Comment: you cann use .net runspaces: https://www.b-blog.info/en/implement-multi-threading-with-net-runspaces-in-powershell.html

Comment: @DheerajMutha, actually there is a free version that contains everything you would require, besides maybe the limited authentication options.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the threadjob method (install-module threadjob) for powershell 5.1.  It takes 5 seconds total, showing that the three functions run in parallel.  All of these ways of passing arguments work.  The order the functions run is random.

```
$init = {
  function function1 { param($myarg) sleep 5; 'function 1' }
  function function2 ($myarg) { sleep 5; 'function 2' }
  function function3 { param($myarg) sleep 5; 'function 3' }
}

get-date
$(
  $a = 1
  start-threadjob -init $init { function1 $using:a }
  start-threadjob -init $init { param($jobarg) function2 $jobarg } -arg 2
  start-threadjob -init $init { function3 $args[0] } -arg 3
) | receive-job -wait -auto
get-date


Thursday, September 29, 2022 1:37:52 PM
function 2
function 1
function 3
Thursday, September 29, 2022 1:37:57 PM
```

Comment: Thanks @js2010. What if we have a argument to pass to the function? How will that work?